# sentry - difference between APP_ID, CLIENT_ID?

Tags: github, sentry

I am installing sentry 10 and trying to use github sso.

In [document from sentry.dev](https://develop.sentry.dev/integrations/github/)
There is an example.

```
# App ID
github-app.id: "GITHUB_APP_ID"
# App Name
github-app.name: "GITHUB_APP_NAME"
# Client ID
github-app.client-id: "GITHUB_CLIENT_ID"
# Client Secret
github-app.client-secret: "GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET"
```

But I am confused between APP_ID and CLIENT_ID.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was using helm chart from [sentry-kubernetes](https://github.com/sentry-kubernetes/charts).

And for `github sso` I had to create `OAuth App` in github.

from [values.yaml](https://github.com/sentry-kubernetes/charts/blob/develop/sentry/values.yaml#L189)

```
githubSso: {} # https://github.com/settings/developers (Create a OAuth App)
  # clientId: "xx"
  # clientSecret: "xx"
```

And if I set github.com's `clientId` in helm's `githubSso.clientId`
It's value is set to environment `GITHUB_APP_ID`

```
GITHUB_APP_ID = '{{ .Values.githubSso.clientId }}'
```

So word `client` and `app` looks like same thing.